# Django get count of each age

Tags: django, orm

I have this model:

```
class User_Data(AbstractUser):
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(null=True,blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=255,default='',null=True,blank=True)
    address = models.TextField(default='',null=True,blank=True)
    gender = models.TextField(default='',null=True,blank=True)
```

And I need to run a django query to get the count of each age. Something like this:

```
Age || Count
10  ||  100
11  ||  50
and so on.....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I did with lambda:

```
usersAge = map(lambda x: calculate_age(x[0]), User_Data.objects.values_list('date_of_birth'))
    users_age_data_source = [[x, usersAge.count(x)] for x in set(usersAge)]
    users_age_data_source = sorted(users_age_data_source, key=itemgetter(0))
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways of doing this. I've had to do something very similar recently. This example works in Postgres.

Note: I've written the following code the way I have so that syntactically it works, and so that I can write between each step. But you can chain these together if you desire.

First we need to annotate the queryset to obtain the 'age' parameter. Since it's not stored as an integer, and can change daily, we can calculate it from the date of birth field by using the database's 'current_date' function:

```py
ud = User_Data.objects.annotate(
    age=RawSQL("""(DATE_PART('year', current_date) - DATE_PART('year', "app_userdata"."date_of_birth"))::integer""", []),
)
```

Note: you'll need to change the "app_userdata" part to match up with the table of your model. You can pick this out of the model's _meta, but this just depends if you want to make this portable or not. If you do, use a string .format() to replace it with what the model's _meta provides. If you don't care about that, just put the table name in there.

Now we pick the 'age' value out so that we get a ValuesQuerySet with just this field

```py
ud = ud.values('age')
```

And then annotate THAT queryset with a count of age

```py
ud = ud.annotate(
    count=Count('age'),
)
```

At this point we have a ValuesQuerySet that has both 'age' and 'count' as fields. Order it so it comes out in a sensible way..

```py
ud = ud.order_by('age')
```

And there you have it.

You must build up the queryset in this order otherwise you'll get some interesting results. i.e; you can't group all the annotates together, because the second one for count depends on the first, and as a kwargs dict has no notion of what order the kwargs were defined in, when the queryset does field/dependency checking, it will fail.

Hope this helps.

If you aren't using Postgres, the only thing you'll need to change is the RawSQL annotation to match whatever database engine it is that you're using. However that engine can get the year of a date, either from a field or from its built in "current date" function..providing you can get that out as an integer, it will work exactly the same way.

Comment: Thanks for the help
I did something similar with lambda

`usersAge = map(lambda x: calculate_age(x[0]), User_Data.objects.values_list('date_of_birth'))
    users_age_data_source = [[x, usersAge.count(x)] for x in set(usersAge)]
    users_age_data_source = sorted(users_age_data_source, key=itemgetter(0))`